# How do I sort my File (highscores) with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm currently working on a dice game for my computer science coursework. I'm on the last bit of it which requires me to sort my highscores into a text file. This is what I have so far

```
player1=input("input") ##Temporary inputs (these values are got from the actual code)
player1score=int(input("input"))


highscore = open("Scores.txt", "r")
whowon=("{0}".format(player1score,player1))
highscores = highscore.readlines()
highscore.close()
highscore = open("Scores.txt", "a")
highscore.write(whowon)
highscore.write("\n")
highscore.close()
highscore = open("Scores.txt", "r")
highscores = highscore.readlines()
highscores.sort()
highscores.reverse()


top1=highscores[0]
top2=highscores[1]
top3=highscores[2]
top4=highscores[3]
top5=highscores[4]

top=("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}".format(top1, top2, top3, top4, top5))

highscore.close()

highscore=open("Scores.txt", "w")
highscore.write(top)
highscore.close()
```

Basically, in the document, it sorts them into order but it disregards the amount of place holders it has. For example:

```
8
7
6943734
5
```

It would only sort it depending on the first place holder. And i dont know how to fix it. Obviously 6943734 should be at the top.

Thanks.

Comment: before highscore.sort() use highscores = [int(x) for x in highscores] because its treated as string

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read. Please use the ``with`` statement to handle files, and avoid re-using the same name for different logical parts (e.g. a file opened for *reading* and for *writing*).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
highscores.sort()
highscores.reverse()
```

with

```
highscores = [ x.rstrip() for x in highscores ]
highscores.sort(reverse=True, key=int)
```

The first line removes newline characters from your strings, so they can be converted to integers using `int()` function, the second - sorts in descending order according to int value.
BTW, this part:

```
top1=highscores[0]
top2=highscores[1]
top3=highscores[2]
top4=highscores[3]
top5=highscores[4]
top=("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}".format(top1, top2, top3, top4, top5))
```

can be shortened to:

```
top = '\n'.join(highscores[0:5])
```

(here you need to add newlines back before writing your highscores to a file).

Comment: i get an invalid syntax in the "key=int"

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped - there's a comma, not a dot between parameters.

Comment: but now, for some reason it doesnt add the new lines between the highscores

Comment: Please read the part of my answer that starts with "BTW". Possibly you need to refresh the page.

Comment: I have read that, but for some reason it doesn't add the "\n" before the .join. Could it be because of my python version? It is 3.5.1

Comment: for the example my highscore text file is
`345643566345464356545643565565435643563543564364356`

It doesnt add a new line inbetween where i want it to